# Stackblur - a very basic difficulty

Tags: jquery, canvas

I apologise in advance for asking what seems like a very basic problem, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I'm trying to follow the advice and source code from the [stackblur demo](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) and have attempted a basic implementation at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QeAQ/1/)

The HTML is:

```
<img id="imgsrc" src="http://benjaminelwyn.com/onelostglove/photos/glove-75.jpg">

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And the JS is:

```
stackBlurImage( 'imgsrc', 'canvas', 20, false );
```

The error I'm getting is the same as the one I was getting on my own site. It says it "cannot access local file". Clearly I'm not doing something right here but I have no idea what.

Any help to put me on my way would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

b

Comment: The console tells me: `Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. ` *and* `Uncaught Error: unable to access image data: Error: unable to access local image data: ReferenceError: netscape is not defined` I think it's the stackblur plugin itself, rather than something you're doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at the source code line 120.

Comment: Like David Thomas, I'm getting the cross-domain security error.  Then your image data is inaccessible so the stackblur plugin toasts itself for lack of image data.  I just ran across this jquery plugin that bounces the image off a Google server to avoid CORS errors (http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/). I haven't tried it, but if you try it, I would be interested in hearing your results.  [Sigh: I wish the powers that be would let us out of the CORS canvas sandbox--it gets very frustrating!]

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. Elclanrs, that's a good spot. I checked it out and made various fiddles to the source code but to no avail. (Different issues...) Might you know how to fix it? I do think it's my problem though because it works fine on the demo...

Comment: Yeah, that issue comes up again and again. Maybe I should add an alert() to the source that explains the situation. So the only solution to blur images that are not hosted on the same or a CORS enabled server is to use a little proxy. Here's an old php script that did the job for the same problem in Flash: http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000407.php
'

Comment: @Quasimondo I wonder if you could update the blur JS files to work with CORS now? http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html I've tried and haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: In additon to what @DrewBaker already mentioned (adding `img.crossOrigin = '';`), you'll also have to enable CORS on the server, e.g. http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html. This fixed that error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use `localhost` instead of `file:///` when running the app and it works fine now.